# Setting Wireless Printer HP Laserjet MFP M177fw

Tags: wireless, 13.10

I've just installed color laserjet pro MFP M177fw on my Ubuntu 13.10 Machine using USB serial port. And scanner also work well.
But I still don't understand how to install wireless printer on it. Perhaps U can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to this answer only one of which I can help you with:  The first part is that you need to make sure that your printer is connecting to your wireless network. You can consult the owners manual for doing this.

For the second part:

On your computer, open a terminal window  - press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>  Enter the command

`hp-setup`

This opens the HP Device Manager setup window.  It shows 4 options - choose the second (Network/Ethernet/Wireless network...)  Click Next

Your computer will scan the local network to see if any printers can be found - when your printer appears on the list, select it and click Next.  The program will then ask if you want to add a description to the printer name, or change some other parameters - you should be good to go from here.